# Exception when releasing a Mutex. What could cause this?

Tags: c#, synchronization, mutex

I'm getting the following exception "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code" when releasing the mutex in the code below:

```
int count = 0;
try
{
     mutex.WaitOne();
     count = requests_sent.Count;
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
     mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

requests_sent is a dictionary that is being accessed (read/write) by other threads but I have no clue why this code is throwing an exception. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the WaitOne() call above the try block.  You only want to release the mutex when you know you acquired it.

You'll now also stand a chance to get a better diagnostic.

Comment: The only situation that the **ReleaseMutex** would raise an exception is if **WaitOne** would raise an exception. so if you move it outside the try block you'll get an uncought exception from the **WaitOne** method

Answer (score 4):

Read the [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex.aspx):

```
ApplicationException    
The calling thread does not own the mutex.
```

The **[WaitOne()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx)** method might throw an exception, without acquiring the mutex. So when you try to release it you get another exception.